# SQL Server trigger not sending email

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, sp-send-dbmail

So, I have a trigger that alerts me when someone makes changes on any table of the database, It was working but suddenly it stopped... the database is still able to send emails (I have more triggers still working) and the insert into my log table is working, so, any idea?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [_trALterTable] 
ON DATABASE 
FOR ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE, CREATE_TABLE
AS 
    DECLARE @_SUBJECT NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @_SUBJECT = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)')


    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'Notifications',
        @recipients = 'my.email@g.com',
        @subject = @_SUBJECT,
        @body = 'Changes on DB';

    INSERT TriggerLog
    SELECT @_SUBJECT, COALESCE(SUSER_SNAME(), USER_NAME()), GETDATE(), HOST_NAME() AS HostName;



GO
```

Comment: Any messages in the Database Mail Log?  Or the SQL Server Log?

Comment: Nope :( but I realized that only alters are not sending emails, while inserts in the log do happen... i think i'll move the email to another trigger on that insert...

Comment: well... that worked.. but i think that's kind of a dirty way of solving the issue... any way, if someone has an idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since inserts where happening regardless of the email being sent or not, i created another trigger after insert that sends the email, that worked, but i guess that isn't a great way of solving this issue, so, if someone has an idea please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because you have `@subject` and `@body` reversed in the call to `sp_send_dbmail`.  Hence, `@subject` might have some characters in it that are not appreciated, but would be fine for `@body`.

Comment: Actually I tried changing that, because i thought that the query could be too long for the subject, but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: @sdmon So now that the triggers are separate, does the email send for ALTER events? It sounds like yes but it is not explicitly clear.

Comment: Yes, it is working now, but I would like to know what was happening :S

Comment: @sdmon I am curious as well :). To be clear, the email is being sent from another DDL trigger OR from an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the `TriggerLog` table? I am wondering if you can test by putting the DDL trigger back the way it was originally, but wrap everything in a TRY / CATCH and do PRINT statements in the CATCH block (or log to a table if you prefer).

Comment: Is an AFTER UPDATE, and after runing this   -create table test (x int)    -ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN x varchar(256)     -drop table test

-Mail queued. (1 row(s) affected)
-Mail queued. (1 row(s) affected)
-Mail queued. (1 row(s) affected)

I get that, but the alter email isn't sent, oh and it doesn't enter to the catch

Comment: @sdmon How about this test: With the `sp_send_dbmail` in the DDL trigger, set the `@subject` param to a literal (like the rest of the params are set). This will help determine if the value of `@_SUBJECT` is having an effect here.